# Communication between Flex with HTML5 / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, apache-flex

I'm building an application in HTML5 with TypeScript and in that application I have created a component to close the session if it's idle for a long time.

Some screens are still in Flex and consequently I'm putting these screens in HTML5 iframes for them to use, whereas I don't migrate to HTML5 + TS.

Is there any way to send some Flex event to html5 so that the component, which closes the session, knew that the flex screen is being used? Or save some information in the Local Storage?

One of the ideas I had was for the component to show a modal asking if the user wants to end the session or not with a 10 second timer.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Nobody runs a flash player anymore...

Comment: Avoid iframes like they're rapists

Comment: It's legacy my friend. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EvertonJosé You dropped this: \

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `ExternalInterface.call`. That will let you run a function in JS and then return its value.